# $C=AB-BA \implies 1-C$ is not nilpotent, where $A,B \in L(V)$ and $V$ is finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$). Let $L(V)$ denote the set of linear transformations on $V$ and $A,B \in L(V)$. Define $C=AB-BA$. I want to guarantee that $1-C$ can not be nilpotent.

I have thought that proof by contradiction is reasonable. I've supposed that $(1-C)^n=0$ for an integer $n>1$. Then, $(1-AB+BA)^n=0$. Intuitively, I expected that my assumption could have contradicted with finite dimensionality of $V$. However, I can not proceed on the proof. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
tr(C)=tr(AB-BA)=tr(AB)-tr(BA)=0,
$$
we have $tr(I-C)=tr(I)=n\neq 0$, hence $I-C$ cannot be nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

$\mbox{tr}(I - AB + BA) = \mbox{tr} (I) - \mbox{tr}(AB) + \mbox{tr}(BA) = n - \mbox{tr}(AB) + \mbox{tr}(AB) = n$

(note that we have used the fact that $\mbox{tr}(BA) = \mbox{tr}(AB)$).

Therefore not all eigenvalues of $I-C$ are zero. This  implies that $I-C$ is not nilpotent.